# CRUD operations on different tables with single method for Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have number of tables in my database. There will be number of methods in DB class if i write a crud operations for every table.

If i can pass name of Table on insertMethod, updateMethod & deleteMethod. Then operation should be performed on that table only.

By this way there will be only 3 methods in DB class and code would be much cleanier.

Does any one have such implementation before in Android?

Thanks,
Zoombie

Comment: You have the solution and yes its possible to do it in code so why don't you implement it by your own rather than asking other do your work.

Comment: Yes Harry, i am working on it now. I asked a question for feasibility of this idea. I will post solution for it in some time. Thanks for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the concept of **Generic Data Access Objects** interesting. You can find an example for hibernate [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects). With a quick google search you can also find [GenericDAO for Android SQLite](http://futureyard.blogspot.com/2009/05/genericdao-for-android-sqlite.html) (did not test it!).

Comment: Yes K.Claszen, I have implemented DB operation is somewhat similar way. Also used singleton pattern for application. Thanks a lot for this..